# Can I allow 2 specific devices on a guest network to see each other?

Tags: wireless-networking, routing, firewall

I have an Apple Airport Extreme. I have set it up in bridge mode because I have a "real" router and network switch. I have also turned on the Guest network.

It appears the Airport Extreme Guest network provides "device isolation" (which also goes by various other names) that prevents clients on the Guest network from seeing each other. According to an article I read, devices on the guest network cannot see any traffic from other devices on the guest network, not even using a packet sniffer. This is good, I generally want it, and it looks like I couldn't turn it off if I wanted to.

However, I have 2 devices that I want on the Guest network because I do not want them accessing the main network or, in general, other devices on the Guest network, but I do want them to see each other. Given that I have

```
  WiFi (bridge mode) -> smart Ethernet switch -> full-function router/firewall
```

and can use the DHCP server on the router to assign fixed, known addresses to the devices, can I connect the 2 devices to each other by appropriately configuring the switch and/or router?

I do not understand what kind of filtering is implemented in the Airport Extreme that prevents the Guest network devices from seeing each other, so I don't know if having the router loop back packets will work, or if that is even the right solution.

I can tell you that the Guest network is implemented as VLAN with ID 1003, and I pass that VLAN through the switch to the router, so the router can route the traffic. I think I was able to get the guest network to see the printer on the main network by adding appropriate rules on the router, but I don't remember, and I no longer have that set up. What I am pretty sure I did not get working was Bonjour advertising the printer to the guest network. So I think in addition to routing device IP to device IP, I need to allow broadcast packets from those devices to reach the other devices.

Is this possible, or does the Airport Extreme use the kind of packet filtering that blocks any such attempt? If it is possible, what is the best way to configure the connection?